# How to get rid of outline around button when focused in jsx element

Tags: reactjs, jsx, outline

Would like to get rid of the blue outline that appears around button when focused.

this is being rendered as jsx element. I've tried the following

```
<Button outline='none'>
{content}
</Button>
```

also tried inline styling

```
style={{outline: 'none'}}
```

Comment: outline none should be working, is `Button` your component or comes from a library ?

Comment: Chakra library component.

Answer (score 1):

With inline style it was setting `bowShadow: 'none'` that resolved this.

```
<Button style={{boxShadow: 'none'}}>
```

Comment: There is an error in your code, try this `<Button style={{ boxShadow: 'none' }}>` but as you mentioned, you're using chakra and it uses it's own props check this list https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/style-props and search for boxShadow you'll find an answer ;)